# TypeError: 'str' object is not callable in generator python

Tags: python, function, generator, yield

```
def gen_secs():
    x = 0
    while x < 60:
        yield x
        x += 1

def gen_minutes():
    x = 0
    while x < 60:
        yield x
        x += 1

def gen_hours():
    x = 0
    while x < 24:
        yield x
        x += 1

def gen_time():
    for x in gen_hours():
        for y in gen_minutes():
            for z in gen_secs():
                yield ("%d:%d:%d" (x, y, z))

for gt in gen_time():
    print(gt)
    if gt == "01:23:45":
        break
```

the the function gen_time cannot return the string param for some
reason. there's syntax problem and I cannot find the issue.

Comment: The expression: `"%d:%d:%d" (x, y, z)` tries to *call the string* `"%d:%d:%d"` with the arguments `(x, y, z)`. But `str` objects are not callable. Please, in the future, try to make a [mcve]. Most of this code is totally irrelevant.

Comment: `yield ("%d:%d:%d" (x, y, z))` You forgot a `%`  between the format string and the arguments.

Comment: Thanks  John Gordon

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You forget the format str syntax, try change the follow:

```
yield ("%d:%d:%d" (x, y, z))
```

to:

```
yield ("%d:%d:%d" % (x, y, z))
```

[This](https://realpython.com/python-formatted-output/) article can be very helpful